# Using python to download a file after clicking the submit button

Tags: python, download, popupwindow

I need to login to a website. Navigate to a report page. After entering the required information and clicking on the "Go" button(This is a multipart/form-data that I am submitting), there's a pop up window asking me to save the file. I want to do it automatically by python.

I search the internet for a couple of days, but can't find a way in python. By using urllib2, I can process up to submitting multipart form, but how can I get the name and location of the file and download it?

Please Note: There is no Href associated with the "Go" button. After submitting the form, a file-save dialog popup asking me where to save the file.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are python bindings to Selenium, that are helping in scripting simulated browser behavior allowing to do really complex stuff with it - take a look at it, should be enough for what you need.